# postman authentication credential not provided - Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, jwt, postman

[postman request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUQSL.png)

I have provided my complete code that I was using to achieve JWT authentication in my django app. I am able to register user, log in but even after providing the token in header, I am having this error in postman.

I have tried multiple options from internet to resolve this issue but nothing is helping, I tried replacing Bearer to Token but that also didn't work.

models.py

```
import uuid
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import PermissionsMixin
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser
from django.utils import timezone

from .managers import CustomUserManager

# Create your models here.
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    # These fields tie to the roles!
    ADMIN = 1
    USER = 2

    ROLE_CHOICES = (
        (ADMIN, 'Admin'),
        (USER, 'User'),
    )
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'user'
        verbose_name_plural = 'users'

      # Roles created here
    uid = models.UUIDField(unique=True, editable=False, default=uuid.uuid4, verbose_name='Public identifier')
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    role = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=ROLE_CHOICES, blank=True, null=True, default=2)
    avtar = models.FileField()
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

serializers.py

```
from .models import User
from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens import RefreshToken
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from django.contrib.auth.models import update_last_login

class UserRegistrationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'email',
            'password'
        )

    def create(self, validated_data):
        auth_user = User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
        return auth_user



class UserLoginSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField()
    password = serializers.CharField(max_length=128, write_only=True)
    access = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)
    refresh = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)
    role = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)

    def create(self, validated_date):
        pass

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        pass

    def validate(self, data):
        email = data['email']
        password = data['password']
        user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)

        if user is None:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Invalid login credentials")

        try:
            refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(user)
            refresh_token = str(refresh)
            access_token = str(refresh.access_token)

            update_last_login(None, user)

            validation = {
                'access': access_token,
                'refresh': refresh_token,
                'email': user.email,
                'role': user.role,
            }

            return validation
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Invalid login credentials")
            
class UserListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'email',
            'role'
        )
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny, IsAuthenticated
# Create your views here.


from .serializers import (
    UserRegistrationSerializer,
    UserLoginSerializer,
    UserListSerializer
)

from .models import User


class UserRegistrationView(APIView):
    serializer_class = UserRegistrationSerializer
    permission_classes = (AllowAny, )

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        valid = serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

        if valid:
            serializer.save()
            status_code = status.HTTP_201_CREATED

            response = {
                'success': True,
                'statusCode': status_code,
                'message': 'User successfully registered!',
                'user': serializer.data
            }

            return Response(response, status=status_code)
        else:
            status_code = status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST

            response = {
                'success': False,
                'statusCode': status_code,
                'message': 'Something Went Wrong!'
            }
            return Response(response, status=status_code)

class AuthUserLoginView(APIView):
    serializer_class = UserLoginSerializer
    permission_classes = (AllowAny, )

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        valid = serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

        if valid:
            status_code = status.HTTP_200_OK

            response = {
                'success': True,
                'statusCode': status_code,
                'message': 'User logged in successfully',
                'access': serializer.data['access'],
                'refresh': serializer.data['refresh'],
                'authenticatedUser': {
                    'email': serializer.data['email'],
                    'role': serializer.data['role']
                }
            }

            return Response(response, status=status_code)
        else:
            status_code = status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST

            response = {
                'success': False,
                'statusCode': status_code,
                'message': 'Something Went Wrong!'
            }
            return Response(response, status=status_code)

class UserListView(APIView):
    serializer_class = UserListSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def get(self, request):
        user = request.user
        if user.role != 1:
            response = {
                'success': False,
                'status_code': status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN,
                'message': 'You are not authorized to perform this action'
            }
            return Response(response, status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)
        else:
            users = User.objects.all()
            serializer = self.serializer_class(users, many=True)
            response = {
                'success': True,
                'status_code': status.HTTP_200_OK,
                'message': 'Successfully fetched users',
                'users': serializer.data

            }
            return Response(response, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

class UserUpdateView(APIView):
    print('inside class')
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    def update(self, request):
        user = request.user
        userDetails = User.objects.get(email=user.email)
        userDetails.first_name = request.POST['first_name']
        userDetails.last_name = request.POST['last_name']
        userDetails.save()
        response = {
            'success': True,
            'status_code': status.HTTP_200_OK,
            'message': 'Deatils Successfully Updated',

        }
        return Response(response, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

[postman header view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VpyTV.png)

settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': ( 
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated', 
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    ),
}

# Configure the JWT settings
SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=5),
    'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=14),
    'ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS': True,
    'BLACKLIST_AFTER_ROTATION': False,
    'ALGORITHM': 'HS256',
    'SIGNING_KEY': SECRET_KEY,
    'VERIFYING_KEY': None,
    'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('JWT',),
    'USER_ID_FIELD': 'id',
    'USER_ID_CLAIM': 'user_id',
    'AUTH_TOKEN_CLASSES': ('rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens.AccessToken',),
    'TOKEN_TYPE_CLAIM': 'token_type',
}
```

managers.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import BaseUserManager
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _


class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    """
    Custom user model where the email address is the unique identifier
    and has an is_admin field to allow access to the admin app 
    """
    def create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError(_("The email must be set"))
        if not password:
            raise ValueError(_("The password must be set"))
        email = self.normalize_email(email)

        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('role', 1)

        if extra_fields.get('role') != 1:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have role of Global Admin')
        return self.create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('token/obtain/', jwt_views.TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_create'),
    path('token/refresh/', jwt_views.TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='token_refresh'),
    path('/UserRegistration/', views.UserRegistrationView.as_view(), name='UserRegistration'),
    path('/AuthUserLogin/', views.AuthUserLoginView.as_view(), name='AuthUserLogin'),
    path('/UserList/', views.UserListView.as_view(), name='UserList'),
    path('/UserUpdate/', views.UserUpdateView.as_view(), name='UserUpdate'),
    path('/UserUpdateAvtar/', views.UserUpdateAvtarView.as_view(), name='UserUpdateAvtar'),
]
```

Comment: Rename the `update` method in `UserUpdateView` class to `post`

Comment: @alamshafi2263 tried that.. nothing changed... please check the postman screenshots as well

Comment: can u please help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75396294/rest-api-detail-user-not-found-code-user-not-found-error-postman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `AUTH_HEADER_TYPES` in `SIMPLE_JWT` settings to
`SIMPLE_JWT['AUTH_HEADER_TYPES'] = ('Bearer', )` or `SIMPLE_JWT['AUTH_HEADER_TYPES'] = ('Bearer', 'JWT')` (if you want to keep `JWT` prefix added before your token. `rest_framework_simplejwt` is looking for prefixes you defined in `SIMPLE_JWT['AUTH_HEADER_TYPES]`. Since it has only `JWT` in there, it is looking for a value in format `JWT {actual token}` in `HTTP_AUTHORIZATION` header.

Or, You can change the Authorization header value in postman - replace `Bearer` with `JWT`.

Comment: thankyou... I removed the simple jwt section from settings.py and it worked..