# Rest api detail User Not Found code user not found Error postman

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, jwt, postman

i am generating a token for each logged in user. But on Get request through postman i am getting this error. please guide me what's wrong !

postman error screenshot

[image]

my models.py

```
class allmodelfields(AbstractBaseUser):
     USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    #id_no = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True,serialize=False,verbose_name="ID",)
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='Email',max_length=255,unique=True,)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=255)  
    confirm_password = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=30,blank = True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30,blank = True)
    number_code = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    phone_no= models.CharField(max_length=10)
    pincode = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    house_no = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    street = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank = True)
    locality = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank = True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    ip = models.CharField(blank = True,max_length = 20)

# auto filled fields
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,)#default = first_name + middle_name + last_name)
    full_number = models.CharField(max_length = 23)#f'{number_code} {phone_no}'
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_ active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    unique_id = models.CharField(max_length = 10, editable=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def full_name_func(self):
        return f'{self.first_name} {self.middle_name} {self.last_name}'


    def full_number_func(self):
        return f'{self.number_code}|{self.phone_no}'

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Customer(allmodelfields):
    account_type = models.CharField(max_length=20,choices=customer_account_choices,default=" ")
class Dealer(allmodelfields):
    account_type = models.CharField(max_length=20,choices= dealer_account_choices,default=" ")
```

serializers.py

```
class customerprofileserializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = ['id','full_name','email','unique_id','full_number']

class dealerprofileserializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Dealer
        fields = ['id','full_name','email','unique_id','full_number']
```

urls.py

```
path("customerprofileview/", customerprofileview.as_view(),name='customerprofileview'),
path("dealerprofileview/", dealerprofileview.as_view(),name='dealerprofileview'),
```

views.py

```
class customerloginview(APIView):
    renderer_classes = [apirenderer]
    def post(self,request,format=None):
        serializer_object = loginserializer(data = request.data)
        if serializer_object.is_valid():
            email = serializer_object.initial_data["email"].lower()
            password= serializer_object.initial_data["password"]
            is_email_exists = Customer.objects.filter(email=email).exists()
            if is_email_exists:
                user = Customer.objects.get(email=email)
                if user.is_active:
                    valid_password = user.check_password(password)
                    if valid_password:
                        #token = get_tokens_for_user(user)
                        refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(user)
                        return Response({'msg':f"{user.full_name} you are logged in successfully !",'tokens':{'access':str(refresh.access_token),'refresh':str(refresh)}},status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
                    else:
                        return Response({'msg':'Incorrect password'})
                else:
                    # resend user activation 
                    current_site = get_current_site(request)
                    mail_subject = 'Please ACTIVATE your ACCOUNT (Resent)'
                    message = render_to_string('account_verification_email.html',{
                    'last_user':user,
                    'domain' : current_site,
                    'id':(user.unique_id)[:4],
                    'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
                    'token': default_token_generator.make_token(user),
                    })
                    to_email = user.email
                    send_email = EmailMessage(mail_subject,message,to=[to_email])
                send_email.send()
                return Response({'msg':f'your account is not activated yet.we have resent an account activation link on {user.email} . please activate then login'})
            else:
                return Response({'msg':'Email does not exist.'})
        else:
            return Response(serializer_object.errors,status = status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

class customerprofileview(APIView):
    renderer_classes = [apirenderer]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    def get(self,request,format=None):
        serializer_object = customerprofileserializer(request.user)
        return Response(serializer_object.data,status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

#same for dealer
```

settings.py

```
SIMPLE_JWT = {
'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=5),
'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=1),
'ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS': False,
'BLACKLIST_AFTER_ROTATION': False,
'UPDATE_LAST_LOGIN': False,

'ALGORITHM': 'HS256',
'SIGNING_KEY': SECRET_KEY,
'VERIFYING_KEY': None,

'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('Bearer',),
'AUTH_HEADER_NAME': 'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION',
'USER_ID_FIELD': 'id',
'USER_ID_CLAIM': 'user_id',
'USER_AUTHENTICATION_RULE': 'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.default_user_authentication_rule',

'AUTH_TOKEN_CLASSES': ('rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens.AccessToken',),
'TOKEN_TYPE_CLAIM': 'token_type',
'TOKEN_USER_CLASS': 'rest_framework_simplejwt.models.TokenUser',

'JTI_CLAIM': 'jti',
```

}

I have searched about it alot but not getting any solution .i want to get the logged in user details such as full name , number , id etc. through generated access token.

have seen a guy doing exactly same thing on youtube .

Answer (score 2):

I have faced the similar problem and i got to know that this is because of settings.
check your JWT default authentication class and AUTH_USER_MODEL. you are working on 3 models. hence u need to override some functions that uses default user model. all the best